# How to see the all the response headers in Node Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to see in Node Exprees enviroment all the headers that are sent to the client

[image: headers]

But when i see do this:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log(res.getHeaders());
});
```

i only see this :

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time you're looking at the outgoing headers, those are the only ones that have been added so far.  The rest will be added by the code that sends the actual response or by other middleware.

If you want to see all the headers that were eventually added to the response before it was sent, you can monitor the `finish` event and THEN look at the headers:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.on('finish', () => {
        console.log(`request url = ${req.originalUrl}`);
        console.log(res.getHeaders());
    });
    next();
});
```

This will sometimes not include the `date`, `content-type` or `content-length` headers unless they are specifically set by the sending code.  This is because if these are not set by the sending code, then the HTTP library adds these headers at a lower level as it is sending the headers and thus `res.getHeaders()` does not retrieve them and never knows about them.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I overlooked your first screenshot... Are you using any middleware? It looks like you're using the [CORS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) middleware, at least - which is why you are showing more headers than the defaults..

It looks like [Node/Express sends](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/1062) a `Content-Length` header when it can..

The `Date` header [is mandatory](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.18) per the HTTP spec, but [it looks like](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_senddate) you can change that behavior in Node/Express - I'm guessing by default Node/Express sets that value to true.

I did test setting `res.sendDate = false` and the date header was not sent, so it looks like that header is set by default for you, most likely as the last step in the response?

---

**With `res.sendDate = false;`**

[image]

---

**Without setting `res.sendDate` (aka the default):**

[image]

---

All in all, I'm assuming the headers you don't see when you `console.log(res.getHeaders())` are set by Node/Express by default..

I wasn't able [to find anything in the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) about default response headers (outside of the Date header), but it's possible I overlooked something. The Express docs don't have anything on it as they just use the built in `http` module from Node.